# Magento Join Custom Collection with Product Collection

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, grid

In Magento 1.9, I Have a custom admin grid.

I have `product id` in my custom collection. I need to add `product name` to that collection.
How to achieve it?

I am using the following code.

```
$productTable = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog/product');
$orders->getSelect()->join( array('product_data'=> $productTable),
'product_data.entity_id = main_table.product_id',
array('product_data.name'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
// Get Attribute Id for name attribute
$entityTypeId = 
Mage::getModel('eav/entity')->setType('catalog_product')->getTypeId();
$prodNameAttrId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
->loadByCode($entityTypeId, 'name')->getAttributeId();

/*
* Join Product SKU and Name into the OrderCollection - Change
collection as per your need
*/

$orders->getSelect()
->join(array('prod' => 'catalog_product_entity'),
'prod.entity_id = main_table.product_id',array('sku'))
->join(array
 ('cpev' => 'catalog_product_entity_varchar'), 
 'cpev.entity_id=prod.entity_id AND 
  cpev.attribute_id='.$prodNameAttrId.'',array('name' => 'value'));
```

Refer [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86157/get-product-name-in-grid)